Intermittent failure writing a file from Powershell script
I have a powershell script that occasionally fails when I run it on a server. I can't reproduce the error on my local system.
The script writes logging information to a file. Lines like this one will fail occasionally:
Write-Output "`nRead the page count" | Out-File -LiteralPath $logfile -Append

Every step in the script gets an entry in the log, so the script writes to this file a lot: I end up with a log file of about 100 kB.
$logfile is a file on a network share. The same share is used for dozens of read and write actions over the course of the script. $logfile will contain about 100 kB of text when the script is done.
If the above line fails, subsequent write commands to the same file will work.
Is there a way to make writing to this log file more robust?

A colleague confirmed that scripts tend to have trouble writing files to that particular network share.
I ended up creating a temporary file:
$logfileTemp=New-TemporaryFile

all of the logging calls go to this file, which is stored locally on the computer running the script. This gets rid of any issues writing to the network share.
Then I made a function to copy the contents from this temporary file to a file on the network share. This function is called at all points where the script could stop processing, to make sure I can access the log file if the script fails.
function Exit-MyScript {
Get-Content -LiteralPath $logfileTemp | Out-File -LiteralPath $logfile -Append -Encoding utf8 
Remove-Item -LiteralPath $logfileTemp | Out-File -LiteralPath $logfile -Append -Encoding utf8
exit
}


Out-File defaults to opening the underlying file stream in a way that doesn't allow for shared write access - so if two running scripts reach a logging statement in close succession, you'll end up with the second script failing because the first one already has an open write-exclusive handle on the file.
You can add the -Force switch to your Out-File statement to make it open the underlying file without write-exclusivity:
Write-Output "`nRead the page count" | Out-File -LiteralPath $logfile -Append -Force


Interesting. Two running scripts should be writing to different folders, so I don't expect that to be an issue, but I do have dozens of lines in this one script that write to $logfile

@Hobbes Hard to say whether that makes sense without more context. Do you have any multi-threading/parallelly executing code in your script? And can you detail how different scripts pick different folders/paths for the log file?

Multithreading: no. Not intentionally, at least. The script does call the occasional external program, using & [command] [arguments]. AIUI, the & means the script will wait until the called command has finished.

Scripts get a path from the process that calls it. This process keeps track of running scripts, and prevents a script from accessing a path that is already in use.
